# imagemapster not initializing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap, imagemapster

I am trying to use the image mapper library to do a mapping of a map, however I can't seem to get the basic features working.

This is the initiation of my scripts

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
        $('central').mapster('tooltip');
        $('#singaporemap').mapster({
            showToolTip: true,
            noHrefIsMask: false,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            stroke: true,
            strokeColor: 'ff0000',
            mapKey: 'data-key',
            singleSelect: true,
            onClick: function (e) {
                $(this).mapster('tooltip');
                alert('something clicked');
            },
            areas: [
                {
                    key: 'central',
                    toolTip: 'central !'
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

And where I create the map:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="height: 68%; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <img src="assets/img/singapore_outline_map.png" id="singaporemap" usemap="#singapore" style="height: 487px; width: 740px" />
    <map name="singapore">
        <area shape="poly" data-key="central" coords="206,141,397,136,444,302,207,238" href="#" alt="Central">
    </map>
</div>
```

I have tried many different codes, most of the code in the initializing doesn't work. My area isn't filling, my onClick doesn't give any alerts, and the area doesn't display tool-tips. Below is the results when I clicked the area I selected

[image: clicked]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a faulty jquery file. 
Using google's hosted one fixed it